# U-boot for Arm on Qemu

Tags: qemu, u-boot

I'm trying to run hello world program on u-boot (ver: u-boot-2010.03-rc3) for ARM on QEMU (ver: qemu-2.5.0)

So far, i have created

-Hello_World.bin

-HelloWorld.uimg using mkimage

-then combined Hello_World and U-Boot binaries into a single image and got flash_hello.bin

Now, when i run the below command,

```
./arm-softmmu/qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -serial stdio -kernel flash_hello.bin
```

QEMU popup is blank and when I enter bootm command with address of the kernel image

I'm getting following output on screen. Can anyone help me with this. Thanks in advance.

> ```
> U-Boot 2010.03-rc3 (Mar 30 2016 - 19:35:25)
>
> DRAM:   0 kB
> Flash: 64 MB
> *** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment
>
> In:    serial
> Out:   serial
> Err:   serial
> Net:   SMC91111-0
> VersatilePB # bootm 0x24E10
> ## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 00024e10 ...
>    Image Name:   
>    Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
>    Data Size:    140 Bytes =  0.1 kB
>    Load Address: 00100000
>    Entry Point:  00100000
>    Loading Kernel Image ... OK
> OK
>
> Starting kernel ...
>
>  C� ��������                     <= This is the output instead of hello world
> ```

Contents of Helloworld.c:

```
volatile unsigned int * const UART0DR = (unsigned int *)0x101f1000;

void print_uart0(const char *s) {
 while(*s != '\0') { /* Loop until end of string */
       *UART0DR = (unsigned int)(*s); /* Transmit char */
       s++; /* Next char */
  }
}

void c_entry() {
  print_uart0("Hello world!\n");
}
```

`

Comment: What happens if you try and run the standard hello world example stand-alone application?

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide information about how you created image files, it is difficult to tell where is wrong.

[This article](https://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/hello-world-for-bare-metal-arm-using-qemu/) show you how to do it in details. You need to specify the data layout for your image file.